# How can I see my place in history during an 'hg rebase' conflict?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Whenever I perform an `hg rebase` and there are merge conflicts, it immediately pulls up an editor for me to resolve the conflict. However, it doesn't give me any information about where in the rebase process I am at. For example, if my history looks as follows:

```
      o  12
      |
      o  11
      |
10 o  |  
    \ /
     o  9
```

Performing `hg rebase -s 11 -d 10` may have a conflict trying to apply either 11 or 12. It is difficult to tell at a glance just from the merge conflict where I am stopped, especially when the graph is larger than this. How can I tell where in the rebase process the conflict is?

Comment: Brilliantly phrased question! :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very recent Mercurials have two configuration options: `[ui] mergemarkertemplate`, and `[ui] pre-merge-tool-output-template`, which can be used to improve this situation a bit.

### `pre-merge-tool-output-template`

`pre-merge-tool-output-template` is printed before running any external merge tool. This can be used to print something before your editor or kdiff3 pops up; note that if you use a terminal-based merge tool (such as most editors unless they're the gui version), it'll likely be hidden by the merge tool. Depending on OS and what program you're using, you may be able to hit Ctrl-Z to suspend your merge tool to see this output.

Example output:

```
merging path/to/file

Running merge tool for path/to/file (/usr/bin/vim):
- local (working copy): 10:2d1f533d add binary file (#2) tip default
-          base (base): 6:abcd1234 some other description default
-    other (merge rev): 9:1e7ad7d7 add binary file (#1) default
... vim runs here ...
```

See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/14589f1989e9/tests/test-merge-tools.t#l1956 for the template that produced that output, `hg help config.ui.pre-merge-tool-output-template` and `hg help templates` for more information on that.

### `mergemarkertemplate`

`mergemarkertemplate` controls the conflict markers you see in your editor.  Set `[ui] mergemarkers=detailed` and see if this is sufficient; if not, you can use `[ui] mergemarkertemplate` to customize it; this can also be customized on a per-merge-tool basis, so see `hg help config.ui.mergemarkers`, `hg help config.ui.mergemarkertemplate`, and `hg help config.merge-tools`.

### Programs with customizable labels

Merge tools like `kdiff3` often have the ability to customizable the labels. In the default configuration, this should be the operation-provided name for the base/local/other (in my example above, this would be `base`, `working copy`, and `merge rev`, respectively. I believe if you have `[ui] mergemarkers=detailed` or `[merge-tools] kdiff3.mergemarkers=detailed`, these will include additional information. See `hg help config.merge-tools` for more information on the per-merge-tool configuration options.

Comment: I do use a terminal based merge tool, and I hadn't thought to check the output. It turns out that even the default pre-merge output has almost enough information to go on. I like your suggested output, though. That looks very helpful to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, exactly, but a bit long for a comment...)

When you write:

> Performing hg rebase -s 11 -d 10 may have a conflict trying to apply
>   either 10 or 11.

do you mean to write

> may have a conflict trying to apply either 11 or 12

? Because you are trying to rebase those csets to 10, so it doesn't make sense to talk about applying 10. Also, consider using the Evolve extension if you aren't already. It makes everything append-only, which is much better.

Also, test in a clone. And also, try rebasing 12 first, if possible. Anyway, Mercurial is just trying to rebase the changes from both 11 and 12, and I don't think it distinguishes between those changes. And why would you expect it to? Isn't it obvious to you which changes belong to which cset?

Also, consider configuring your merge setup for use with `kdiff3`, if you aren't already. It makes things much clearer to do things in a merge editor, and you can also see both sides of the merge clearly. See 
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration and https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KDiff3

Personally, I have the following lines in my `~/.hgrc`, but they've been there a long time, and I don't remember where I got them from. Also, I don't do merges much these days. But for whatever it is worth...

```
[merge-tools]
kdiff3.args=--auto --L1 base --L2 local --L3 other $base $local $other -o $output
kdiff3.regkey=Software\KDiff3
kdiff3.regappend=\kdiff3.exe
kdiff3.fixeol=True
kdiff3.gui=True
kdiff3.diffargs=--L1 '$plabel1' --L2 '$clabel' $parent $child
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You're correct about my mistake -- I did intend to say "apply either 11 or 12"

Comment: In response: mercurial's rebase applies changes from each descendant changeset of the source one at a time to the destination.

So the rebase operation first tries to apply 11 to 10. If it runs into conflicts, it gives you the ability to resolve here. After resolving all conflicts, it will apply 12 to the resulting working directory. In this way, it "distinguishes between those changes."

This is especially important if there are multiple heads in the source's descendants.

Comment: @geppettodivacin It sounds like you might be better off rebasing 11 and then rebasing 12, one at a time.

Comment: While that's technically not a rebase, since rebase moves all descendants with it, that could be done with graft. That would work, if a little tedious for larger examples. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @geppettodivacin True, `hg rebase` would (as far as I know), insist on moving the cset and all descendants, a more manual approach is definitely possible.